# how to make an MovieClip transparent?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have this situation:

there is some generic movieclip with some color in background (can be green, red, etc), and I load one image and attach in this movieclip as a child, using the same dimensions of the movieclip.

But if this image has some transparency I can see the background ( green, red, etc).

I try this:

```
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, function(e:Event){
var tempImage:Bitmap = new Bitmap(e.target.content.bitmapData);
image.bitmapData = tempImage.bitmapData;

obj.graphics.beginFill(0xFFFFFF, 0);
obj.graphics.drawRect(0,0,obj.width, obj.height);
obj.graphics.endFill();

obj.addChild(image);
});
```

But it is not working. And I cant change the obj.alpha because I cant see the image in this case. There is another way?

Thanks

Comment: How is the background color being drawn? Are you using the drawing API, or is it another display object inside `obj`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried Bitmapfill instead?

```
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, function(e:Event){

    obj.graphics.beginBitmapFill(e.target.content.bitmapData);
    obj.graphics.endFill();
});
```